# Unable to setup the load function

Tags: apache-pig

I can't figure out the issue here.Load statement is failing with the error `ERROR 2088: Fetch failed. Couldn't retrieve result`

```
raw_data = LOAD 'files/test4.txt' AS (lines:chararray);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most probably the file path is incorrect.Are you missing a forward slash `/files/test4.txt`?

```
raw_data = LOAD '/files/test4.txt' AS (lines:chararray);
```